# How to get out edges with label/class over OrientDB java api

Tags: java, orientdb

I want to get the out edges starting with one vertex using one or multiple classes/labels over the java api.

This is my example code, which causes NPE.
I tried using Edge and OrientEdge.

```
private Iterable<OrientEdge> queryNextEdges(OrientVertex vertex) {
    OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(
            "remote:127.0.0.1:2424/xyz", "admin", "admin"
    ).setupPool(1, 10);
    OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx();
    Iterable<OrientEdge> queryResult;
    try {
        queryResult = (Iterable<OrientEdge>) (OrientEdge) vertex.getEdges(Direction.OUT, "hierarchy");
    } finally {
        graph.shutdown();
    }
    return queryResult;
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex.getFieldNames(OrientVertex.java:1042)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex.getEdges(OrientVertex.java:810)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex.getEdges(OrientVertex.java:782)
at ebs.window.graphLayout.GraphLayoutPresenter.queryNextEdges(GraphLayoutPresenter.java:214)
```

Comment: It looks like the `vertex` has NULL the settings attributed. How did you get the vertex?

Comment: Why are you creating `OrientGraphFactory` and `OrientGraph` instances without using'em?

Comment: @IvanMainetti yes, you are right its leftover code of other things I tried, sorry.

Comment: @Lvca you are right something is wrong with the vertex, not the way I get the edges. I tried it getting the vertex another way and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to reproduce your example and it works.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried getting the vertex your way and it worked. It helped me to pinpoint the mistake in my code. It was not in the way I got the edge but in the vertex I used in the first place

Comment: @Wozilla: Since this works, perhaps mark this as the correct answer

Comment: Thats fair. But for other people who read this, just to prevent confusion. This example is not exactly the solution for my Error but still a working example.